# adding orders/customers management to my PHP ecommerce website

Tags: php, e-commerce

I have an online shop I am coding myself in PHP, on the admin side I have what I need to manage the front end, and the catalog.

I still have to build admin for orders / customers / inventory and reports' interfaces.
I realize it is a lot of work and I am looking for a solution to accelerate the process so that I can focus more on running/expanding my business.

I looked into many eCommerce solutions to see if I could use their admin part, but not the store front and catalog, with no luck so far.

Another solution I am considering is hiring a PHP programmer (with knowledge of mysql/Javascript/XHTML/CSS) to work with me in getting this code written, but I have no idea where to start looking for such a person.

any advice?

EDIT

thank you for the answers so far, I see I need clarifications:

I am already running the website, and selling from it, this is where most of our company income comes from. We just use too much time to handle orders manually.

I contacted 2 software house looking for help and they both offered their help, but both want to re-code all I have so far under the framework/language of their choice, and from there add the new functionality I need.
I figured that would require a lot of homework from me providing all the analysis and documentation, plus the time I would need to be on hold waiting for them to re-produce what I just did, and at that point I would have spent about $10.000 at least... and not yet started to get what I need, just want I have already (but in a format where I might not be able to work on myself)

I understand that approach might have benefits in the long run, especially if I manage to stay in business.

What I think might be smarter for me would be either:

a) find a eCommerce I can adapt to my immediate needs (managing orders/customers)
b) find a programmer to work with me on my current code to help me get where I want to go faster and with something I can maintain/modify myself if I need.

I'd like option (b) I might still end up spending $10.000 (let's say) but I would get what I actually want, that is the orders/customer management , and not a new website similar to what I have already.

in the meanwhile I keep coding myself, but I lack of time.

Answer (score 0):

instead of starting by what you assumed about the project first plan the project. while planing in proper way you will get new requirements (those are not in the initial stage). After planing everything if you feel your final product should be like this then start coding otherwise include the all functionality those fulfill the remaining requirements to complete the project as perfect one.

And to get any employee use any media

Comment: thank you for your comment, I updated my post, I realized I haven't been clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a good PHP programmer to develop a good custom eCommerce solution would likely cost you quite a bit of money (or you would likely get a really bad product).  Or, they might rip you off and just sell you an open source product and charge lots to implement.

If you're just looking for more of a billing/CRM system, there should be quite a few open source or hosted solutions out there for you that would have much lower upfront costs.

Not sure if something as simple as Simplify might work for you:

http://www.shopify.com/

Some other possibilities:

http://sales.about.com/od/leadgeneration/a/freecrmsoftware.htm

I don't have much experience with inventory systems specifically,

Comment: thank you! I keep looking into those and more, it always seems so much work to chop them to extract what I need...

Answer (score 0):

Quite late but for anyone looking for something similar in the future this might be helpful.

You could potentially use something like [**Moltin**](https://molt.in) and just integrate with the components in the [**API**](http://docs.molt.in) that you need.

Doesn't matter what framework/language you're using.